# SQL percentage calculation over the hour

Tags: sql

I have a table consisting of thousands of devices similar to the one below, and I want to calculate the time spent by the devices in certain locations as a percentage on an hourly basis using this table.

(Values are given as an example.)

| device | geohash | gridtype | total_hour_count | total_day_count | avg_spent_hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67a47cd76baff7e2 | sxk9g3 | Work | 500 | 25 | 20.00 |
| 67a47cd76baff7e2 | swy9g3 | Home | 590 | 27 | 18.00 |
| 67a47cd76baff7e2 | szbvfd | Other | 420 | 18 | 9.28 |
| 02d171810d7ae1f5 | swdvdf | Home | 274 | 30 | 18,54 |
| 02d171810d7ae1f5 | sdefvx | Work | 184 | 22 | 17,51 |
| 02d171810d7ae1f5 | dfvcxv | Other | 122 | 19 | 14,12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

As an example the desired output:

| deviceid | home_percent | work_percent | other_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67a47cd76baff7e2 | 35 | 35 | 30 |
| 02d171810d7ae1f5 | 50 | 25 | 25 |
| 784faeff1c8b76c1 | 90 | 5 | 5 |
| 28fa9ca3dfff8a6f | 80 | 10 | 10 |
| f2f6324d5149e336 | 80 | 0 | 20 |
| d84410d139981c19 | 25 | 50 | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: What is the problem - percentage calculation or pivotting this data?

Comment: You may also add an explanation how you dedoced the different percentages

Comment: Just a tip, make it easy to assists you. Sample values like A, B and C are so much easier to read than 784faeff128b76c1, 784faeff1c8b75c1 and 784farff1c8b76c1.